# HyperLedger Fabric composer playground Reference error require not defined

Tags: javascript, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I am trying to build a car auction network with composer playground the error occurs when I am at the stage to make an offer to an auction and after that every  new registry I try to make gets this error Reference error: require not defined i am familiar with JavaScript but I am not sure what causing this error .

```
'use strict';

const AdminConnection = require('composer-admin').AdminConnection;
const BusinessNetworkConnection = require('composer-client').BusinessNetworkConnection;
const { BusinessNetworkDefinition, CertificateUtil, IdCard } = require('composer-common');
const path = require('path');

require('chai').should();

const NS = 'org.acme.vehicle.auction';

describe('CarAuction', () => {
  // In-memory card store for testing so cards are not persisted to the file system
  const cardStore = require('composer-common').NetworkCardStoreManager.getCardStore( { type: 'composer-wallet-inmemory' } );
  let adminConnection;
  let businessNetworkConnection;

  before(async () => {
      // Embedded connection used for local testing
      const connectionProfile = {
          name: 'embedded',
          'x-type': 'embedded'
      };
      // Generate certificates for use with the embedded connection
      const credentials = CertificateUtil.generate({ commonName: 'admin' });

      // PeerAdmin identity used with the admin connection to deploy business networks
      const deployerMetadata = {
          version: 1,
          userName: 'PeerAdmin',
          roles: [ 'PeerAdmin', 'ChannelAdmin' ]
      };
      const deployerCard = new IdCard(deployerMetadata, connectionProfile);
      deployerCard.setCredentials(credentials);

      const deployerCardName = 'PeerAdmin';
      adminConnection = new AdminConnection({ cardStore: cardStore });

      await adminConnection.importCard(deployerCardName, deployerCard);
      await adminConnection.connect(deployerCardName);
  });

  beforeEach(async () => {
      businessNetworkConnection = new BusinessNetworkConnection({ cardStore: cardStore });

      const adminUserName = 'admin';
      let adminCardName;
      let businessNetworkDefinition = await BusinessNetworkDefinition.fromDirectory(path.resolve(__dirname, '..'));

      // Install the Composer runtime for the new business network
      await adminConnection.install(businessNetworkDefinition);

      // Start the business network and configure an network admin identity
      const startOptions = {
          networkAdmins: [
              {
                  userName: adminUserName,
                  enrollmentSecret: 'adminpw'
              }
          ]
      };
      const adminCards = await adminConnection.start(businessNetworkDefinition.getName(), businessNetworkDefinition.getVersion(), startOptions);

      // Import the network admin identity for us to use
      adminCardName = `${adminUserName}@${businessNetworkDefinition.getName()}`;
      await adminConnection.importCard(adminCardName, adminCards.get(adminUserName));

      // Connect to the business network using the network admin identity
      await businessNetworkConnection.connect(adminCardName);
  });

  describe('#makeOffer', () => {

      it('should add the offer to the offers of a vehicle listing', async () => {

          const factory = businessNetworkConnection.getBusinessNetwork().getFactory();

          // create the auctioneer
          const seller = factory.newResource(NS, 'Member', 'daniel.selman@example.com');
          seller.firstName = 'Dan';
          seller.lastName = 'Selman';
          seller.balance = 0;

          // create the vehicle
          const vehicle = factory.newResource(NS, 'Vehicle', 'CAR_001');
          vehicle.owner = factory.newRelationship(NS, 'Member', seller.$identifier);

          // create the vehicle listing
          const listing = factory.newResource(NS, 'VehicleListing', 'LISTING_001');
          listing.reservePrice = 100;
          listing.description = 'My nice car';
          listing.state = 'FOR_SALE';
          listing.vehicle = factory.newRelationship(NS, 'Vehicle', 'CAR_001');

          // create the buyer
          const buyer = factory.newResource(NS, 'Member', 'sstone1@example.com');
          buyer.firstName = 'Simon';
          buyer.lastName = 'Stone';
          buyer.balance = 1000;

          // create another potential buyer
          const buyer2 = factory.newResource(NS, 'Member', 'whitemat@example.com');
          buyer2.firstName = 'Matthew';
          buyer2.lastName = 'White';
          buyer2.balance = 100;

          // create the auctioneer
          const auctioneer = factory.newResource(NS, 'Auctioneer', 'boss@auction.com');
          auctioneer.firstName = 'Mr';
          auctioneer.lastName = 'Smith';

          const offer = factory.newTransaction(NS, 'Offer');
          offer.member = factory.newRelationship(NS, 'Member', buyer.$identifier);
          offer.listing = factory.newRelationship(NS, 'VehicleListing', 'LISTING_001');
          offer.bidPrice = 200;

          // Get the registries.
          const vehicleRegistry = await businessNetworkConnection.getAssetRegistry(NS + '.Vehicle');
          const vehicleListingRegistry = await businessNetworkConnection.getAssetRegistry(NS + '.VehicleListing');
          const userRegistry = await businessNetworkConnection.getParticipantRegistry(NS + '.Member');
          const auctioneerRegistry = await businessNetworkConnection.getParticipantRegistry(NS + '.Auctioneer');

          // Add the Vehicle to the asset registry.
          await vehicleRegistry.add(vehicle);

          // Add the VehicleListing to the asset registry
          await vehicleListingRegistry.add(listing);

          // add the members
          await userRegistry.addAll([buyer, buyer2, seller]);

          // add the auctioneers
          await auctioneerRegistry.addAll([auctioneer]);

          // Create the offer transaction and submit
          await businessNetworkConnection.submitTransaction(offer);

          // Create the offer transaction and submit
          const lowOffer = factory.newTransaction(NS, 'Offer');
          lowOffer.member = factory.newRelationship(NS, 'Member', buyer2.$identifier);
          lowOffer.listing = factory.newRelationship(NS, 'VehicleListing', 'LISTING_001');
          lowOffer.bidPrice = 50;
          await businessNetworkConnection.submitTransaction(lowOffer);

          // get the listing
          let newListing = await vehicleListingRegistry.get(listing.$identifier);

          // both offers should have been added to the listing
          newListing.offers.length.should.equal(2);

          // close the bidding
          const closeBidding = factory.newTransaction(NS, 'CloseBidding');
          closeBidding.listing = factory.newRelationship(NS, 'VehicleListing', 'LISTING_001');
          await businessNetworkConnection.submitTransaction(closeBidding);

          // get the listing
          newListing = await vehicleListingRegistry.get(listing.$identifier);

          // the offer should have been added to the listing
          newListing.state.should.equal('SOLD');

          // get the buyer and seller
          const theBuyer = await userRegistry.get(buyer.$identifier);
          const theSeller = await userRegistry.get(seller.$identifier);

          // check the buyer's balance
          theBuyer.balance.should.equal(800);

          // check the seller's balance
          theSeller.balance.should.equal(200);

          // get the vehicle
          const theVehicle = await vehicleRegistry.get(vehicle.$identifier);

          // check that the buyer now owns the car
          theVehicle.owner.getIdentifier().should.equal(buyer.$identifier);
      });

      describe('#closeBidding', () => {
          it('with no bids should result in RESERVE_NOT_MET', async () => {
              const factory = businessNetworkConnection.getBusinessNetwork().getFactory();

              const seller = factory.newResource(NS, 'Member', 'daniel.selman@example.com');
              seller.firstName = 'Dan';
              seller.lastName = 'Selman';
              seller.balance = 0;

              // create the vehicle
              const vehicle = factory.newResource(NS, 'Vehicle', 'CAR_001');
              vehicle.owner = factory.newRelationship(NS, 'Member', seller.$identifier);

              // create the vehicle listing
              const listing = factory.newResource(NS, 'VehicleListing', 'LISTING_001');
              listing.reservePrice = 100;
              listing.description = 'My nice car';
              listing.state = 'FOR_SALE';
              listing.vehicle = factory.newRelationship(NS, 'Vehicle', vehicle.$identifier);

              // Get the registries.
              const vehicleRegistry = await businessNetworkConnection.getAssetRegistry(NS + '.Vehicle');
              const vehicleListingRegistry = await businessNetworkConnection.getAssetRegistry(NS + '.VehicleListing');
              const userRegistry = await businessNetworkConnection.getParticipantRegistry(NS + '.Member');

              // Add the Vehicle to the asset registry.
              await vehicleRegistry.add(vehicle);

              // add the seller to the member registry
              await userRegistry.add(seller);

              // add the vehicle listing
              await vehicleListingRegistry.add(listing);

              // close the bidding
              const closeBidding = factory.newTransaction(NS, 'CloseBidding');
              closeBidding.listing = factory.newRelationship(NS, 'VehicleListing', listing.$identifier);
              await businessNetworkConnection.submitTransaction(closeBidding);

              // get the listing and check state
              const vehicleListing = await vehicleListingRegistry.get(listing.$identifier);
              vehicleListing.state.should.equal('RESERVE_NOT_MET');
          });
      });
  });
});
```

Comment: Could you tell me why you are using hyperledger composer and what you are hoping to learn by using it ?, I would not recommend anyone use hyperledger composer anymore. It's end of life and the community has moved on.

Comment: It is required to use hypereledger composer unfortunately, I know the developers stoped supporting it

Comment: I'd be interested to know who says it's required and what the purpose of this requirement eg what are they trying to teach you and maybe I can suggest a better alternative.

Comment: It is a small project to get familiar with the blockchain technology

Comment: Hyperledger composer doesn't get you familiar with blockchain technology really. It demonstrates the concept of digital assets and you could use hyperledger fabric to provide the environment to run the application (and in the old days of hyperledger fabric, make it easier to develop applications that could run on fabric). 
You would be better off using hyperledger fabric (looking at the asset samples in hyperledger fabric) and using the IBM Blockchain extension available for VS Code  IMO.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `require` in a hyperledger composer business network implementation as you see you get an error because the require keyword is not available.

If you want to learn about blockchain technology then you should not use hyperledger composer because it isn't a blockchain technology. Hyperledger Fabric is a blockchain technology and that would be far more worthwhile investing time to understand.

Hyperledger composer was a framework for business networks that could use hyperledger fabric blockchain technology to provide the persistence, immutability etc of the information that it wanted to store